# How to implement back hardware key in multipage webapp in tizen

Tags: web-applications, back-button, tizen, multipage

I am pretty new to tizen app development .I am developing a multipage app using Tizen Web UI Builder. How can I implement hardware back key for going back to previous page? 
I have already tried using this.

```
document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {
var activePage = $.mobile.activePage().attr('id'); // read current page
switch(e.keyName)
{
case 'back':
    switch(activePage)
    {
        case 'page1':
            tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
            break;
        default:
            parent.history.back();
            break;
    }
    break;
case 'menu':
    switch(activePage)
    {
        case 'page2':
            console.log('you are on '+activePage);
            break;
        default:
            //TODO: Do something
            break;
    }`enter code here`
break;
}});`
```

Comment: ...and this isn't working for you? What is your application HTML markup?

Answer (score 2):

Please try out the below code , it will work :

```
window.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {
  var activePage = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');
  switch (e.keyName) {
  case 'back':
    switch (activePage) {
    case 'page1': // use your first page or another page where the application should close if the use press back
      tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
      //tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
      break;
    case 'page2':
      window.history.back(history);
      break;
    case 'page3':
      window.history.back(history);
    default: // if no case available, the back button returns back to previous page
      console.log("Do something");
      //$.mobile.back();
    }
    break;
  }
});
```