# TIZEN Hardware Buttons BACK - MENU ... How to program

Tags: button, menu, back, tizen, tizen-web-app

I am sure these questions and hopefully answers will help a lot of users! The Tizen documentation is difficult to understand at best. The Tizen Studio sample for the BACK BUTTON is for one single index.html page. When the back button is pressed, it only goes to a different < div > on the same "page", not to a different html docs (Example: page1.html, page2.html, page_new.html, page_bart.html, etc.)

I have searched Tizen Forums, Google and Stackoverflow. The closets I have come to an answer is below.

Unfortunately, both questions and answers are from 2015, for version 2.3 AND did not work.

LINK HERE:
[Stack overflow Tizen 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109440/on-click-of-hardware-button-of-mobile-then-it-should-exit-from-tizen-application/31164295#31164295)

AND HERE:
[Stack overflow Tizen 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712042/how-to-implement-back-hardware-key-in-multipage-webapp-in-tizen)

**Here is what I have:**

Tizen Studio 1.2, TAU Web App, Tizen version 2.4, All code is HTML5 with a little java, Everything works...(except for below).

**Here is what I need:**

1. When a user is on page10.html (Example, any page) and presses the back button the "tau web app" simply goes back to page9.html. If they press it again, it goes back to page8.html. If they press it again page7, etc..
2. If the user presses the Menu button, a pop up (like the TIZEN sample app) says, "Do you want to exit the app? with options YES or NO.
   If user presses YES the web app (or browser) window closes immediately. If user presses NO the pop-up closes immediately and the user stays on that page.
3. At the end of my app I have a button that says "The End". When the user clicks this it closes the web app (or browser window) immediately.
4. THIS REQUEST IS OPTIONAL, but why not...the capabilities are a few code lines away. Currently every page (I have over 100) jumps or cuts from one to the other. I would like to use a page transition (maybe a page slide, can I try others?). Is there a page turn?

PLEASE you Code Wizards! My app is done but I have been stuck trying to get the hardware key buttons to work! I am POSITIVE that other Tizen developers would also appreciate working code for the above issues!

I thank you in advance!

Here is the link to download all the code:

"TIZEN HARDWARE PUZZLE.PDF" 
LINK HERE:
[Single PDF with lots of TIZEN code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B69oZrAzAWodUDJGNjFZeGpIeEE)

This .pdf shows my current code, some sample code from Tizen and anything I could find online about the TIZEN BACK BUTTON.

There is just one more itty, bitty, tiny request (**AN IMPORTANT ONE**)......

**Can you PLEASE tell me where the code is inserted!?!**

For example:

```
<!-- Put this code anywhere in main.js -->

<script>EXAMPLE</script>

<!-- End -->
```

or

```
<!-- Put this code in the Head on EACH page -->

<script>EXAMPLE</script>

<!-- End -->
```

or

```
<!-- Put this code in the Body on index.html page -->

 <script>EXAMPLE</script>

<!-- End -->
```

This will **HELP EVERYONE** who is just starting out like me! We really need to know where to place the code, not just here it is! **THANK YOU!**

Stackoverflow is THE BEST!!!

====================================

Comment: I couldn't understand the 4th one. Please clarify it and check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use TAU to fulfill the first three requirements of your post's "Here is what I need:" section. It offers a collection of UI components that simplify application coding.

I would like to suggest you to go through the **TAUUIComponents** sample app in Tizen Studio.

For the first requirement i.e. the pagination thing, you may go through the **app.js** and try to realize how it's managing the hardware back key event to get back to previous page.

For second one i.e. the pop thing, go through **moremenu.js** here you'll find code as below:

```
menukeyHandler = function (ev) {
    if( ev.keyName === "menu" ) {
        if (morePopup.classList.contains("ui-popup-active")) {
            tau.closePopup();
        } else {
            tau.openPopup("#moremenu");
        }
    }
};
```

Now, go through moremenu.html file and modify as below:

```
<div id="moremenu" class="ui-popup ui-popup-moremenu">
            <div class="ui-popup-content">
              <div class="ui-popup-content popup-content-padding">
                Do you want to exit the app?
            </div>
                 <div class="ui-popup-footer ui-grid-col-2">
                <a class="ui-btn" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Yes</a>
                <a class="ui-btn" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">No</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I guess, once you've completed above two then you'll be able to complete the 3rd requirement also.

To know more about TAU components you may go through this links:

1. https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/ui_fw_api/Mobile_UIComponents/mobile_component_list.htm
2. https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/user-interface/tizen-advanced-ui/hello-world